# Chrome Extension: Replace selected text in textarea with clipboard data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, textarea, clipboard

I'm having a hell of a time trying to insert text into an HTML textarea, or grab data from the clipboard with a Chrome extension (using a context menu).

I currently have these permissions in my manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [
  "contextMenus",
  "clipboardRead",
  "clipboardWrite"],
```

My javascript skills are still pretty elementary, but despite spending quite a while on SO I can't seem to overcome security issues with document.execCode('paste') or the specific syntax I require to insert text in the text box.

Programatically this is what I'd imagine the function would do:

1. Get the selected string in the current textarea and copy to a
   variable "orig_str".
2. If a string, get the current clipboard and
   store it in a variable "clip_str". If not, set variable to nothing.
3. Overwrite the original selected string in the current textarea with
   "orig_str + clip_str".

So if the textarea contained:

```
I eat peas
```

and the clipboard contained:

```
 and cook
```

and the user selected "eat", then the function was activated, the string in the textarea would be changed to read:

```
I eat and cook peas
```

Any help down the right path would be appreciated, preferably with straight JS rather than JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Chrome extentions access the clipboard so I imagine you have clipboard string in `clipboard` variable. Then you can read selected text in the browser by `window.getSelection` function:

```
var selection = new window.getSelection,
    selectedText = selection.anchorNode.data,
    textarea = window.document.querySelector('textarea');
```

rest is easy just concat two strings:

```
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(selectedText, clipboard);
```

Comment: > textarea.value.replace(selectedText, clipboard);

This would replace all instances instead of just the selected bit.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this I use in my extension here: https://github.com/horejsek/specialCharacters. I hope that's help.